# select sum column by with Mongodb and Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb

I have MongoDB document which contains following data(xxx)

```
{ 
   "_id" : "48e5f6b1-026f-48b8-98cb-6572cfa0eaa6", 
   "esti_delivery_time" : "2015-1-1",
   "original_price" : NumberInt(4060),
   "price":109.2,
   "code" : "JS1709137", 
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-13T06:01:18.000+0000"), 
   "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-13T03:45:54.000+0000")
}
```

I want to

```
 SELECT "xxx" with SUM "price" and SUM "original_price"
```

Comment: What is your expected output what is xxx

Comment: Meta topic [Code Translation Tagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging) . Such questions really are highly off-topic without showing some attempt.

Comment: @Zach do not forget to mark the answer or add your if there no the right answer. This question can be useful for other in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need the sums of the `price` and `original_price` elements, it is means that you need to group the documents by some data (one or more elements). For this task you need to use the [$group aggregator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group).

[MongoDB PHP Driver documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/)

Example:

```
$con = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017', [], [
    'typeMap' => [
        'root'     => 'array',
        'document' => 'array',
        'array'    => 'array'
    ]
]);
$collection = $con->selectDatabase("db_name")->selectCollection("collection_name");

$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    [
        '$group' => [
            "_id" => '$code',
            "sum_price" => ['$sum' => '$price'],
            "sum_original_price" => ['$sum' => '$original_price']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yysag.png)

Thanks  for  your reply